# Notification not Queuable on Laravel 5.4 (SlackMessage)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, queue, laravel-5.4

I started to use notification system on Slack provided by Laravel 5.4 and it is awesome (src: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/notifications)!

However I have a problem to notify with a queue it triggers an Exception: Serialization of 'Closure' is not allowed in /var/www/project_test/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Queue.php:125

Can you help me please, what is my mistake ?

Information :

- it works well without Queue
- queue driver is database
- queue worker is started with 'queue:work --queue=default,mail --sleep=3 --tries=3 --timeout=60'

Here my code in app/Notifications/Slack.php :

```
namespace App\Notifications;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notification;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\SlackMessage;

class Slack extends Notification implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Queueable;

    private $channel;
    private $username;
    private $icon;
    private $message;
    /**
     * Create a new notification instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(String $channel = '', String $username = '', String $icon = '', String $message = '')
    {
        $this->channel = $channel;
        $this->username = $username;
        $this->icon = $icon;
        $this->message = $message;
    }
    /**
     * Get the notification's delivery channels.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return array
     */
    public function via($notifiable)
    {
        return ['slack'];
    }
    /**
    * Get the Slack representation of the notification.
    *
    * @param  mixed  $notifiable
    * @return SlackMessage
    */
    public function toSlack($notifiable)
    {
        return (new SlackMessage)
                ->from($this->username, $this->icon)
                ->to($this->channel)
                ->content($this->message);
    }
    /**
    * Get the array representation of the notification.
    *
    * @param  mixed  $notifiable
    * @return array
    */
    public function toArray($notifiable)
    {
        return [
            'channel' => $this->channel,
            'username' => $this->username,
            'icon' => $this->icon,
            'message' => $this->message,
        ];
    }
}
```

Here my code in app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php which use slack notifications:

```
namespace App\Providers;
use Queue;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;
use Illuminate\Queue\Events\JobFailed;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use App\Notifications\Slack;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    use Notifiable;
    /**
     * Route notifications for the Slack channel.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function routeNotificationForSlack()
    {
        return 'http://hook.slack.com/XXXXXx/my_slack_endpoint';
    }
    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        // When a queue job fail
        Queue::failing(function (JobFailed $event) {
            // Notify team of failing job
            $when = Carbon::now()->addSeconds(10);
            $this->notify((new Slack('slack_channel', 'slack_username', 'slack_icon', 'Job Failed !'))->delay($when));
        });
    }

    /**
     * Register any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        //
    }
}
```

Full error dump :

```
local.ERROR: Exception: Serialization of 'Closure' is not allowed in /var/www/project_test/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Queue.php:125
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/project_test/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Queue.php(125): serialize(Object(Illuminate\Notifications\SendQueuedNotifications))
#1 /var/www/project_test/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Queue.php(106): Illuminate\Queue\Queue->createObjectPayload(Object(Illuminate\Notifications\SendQueuedNotifications))
#2 /var/www/project_test/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Queue.php(86): Illuminate\Queue\Queue->createPayloadArray(Object(Illuminate\Notifications\SendQueuedNotifications), '', NULL)
#3 /var/www/project_test/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/DatabaseQueue.php(108): Illuminate\Queue\Queue->createPayload(Object(Illuminate\Notifications\SendQueuedNotifications), '')
#4 /var/www/project_test/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Bus/Dispatcher.php(181): Illuminate\Queue\DatabaseQueue->later(Object(Carbon\Carbon), Object(Illuminate\Notifications\SendQueuedNotifications))
#5 /var/www/project_test/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Bus/Dispatcher.php(159): Illuminate\Bus\Dispatcher->pushCommandToQueue(Object(Illuminate\Queue\DatabaseQueue), Object(Illuminate\Notifications\SendQueuedNotifications))
#6 /var/www/project_test/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Bus/Dispatcher.php(73): Illuminate\Bus\Dispatcher->dispatchToQueue(Object(Illuminate\Notifications\SendQueuedNotifications))
#7 /var/www/project_test/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Notifications/NotificationSender.php(160): Illuminate\Bus\Dispatcher->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\Notifications\SendQueuedNotifications))
#8 /var/www/project_test/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Notifications/NotificationSender.php(61): Illuminate\Notifications\NotificationSender->queueNotification(Array, Object(App\Notifications\Slack))
#9 /var/www/project_test/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Notifications/ChannelManager.php(36): Illuminate\Notifications\NotificationSender->send(Array, Object(App\Notifications\Slack))
#10 /var/www/project_test/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Notifications/RoutesNotifications.php(18): Illuminate\Notifications\ChannelManager->send(Object(App\Providers\AppServiceProvider), Object(App\Notifications\Slack))
#11 /var/www/project_test/app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php(57): App\Providers\AppServiceProvider->notify(Object(App\Notifications\Slack))
#12 /var/www/project_test/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Events/Dispatcher.php(334): App\Providers\AppServiceProvider->App\Providers\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Queue\Events\JobFailed))
#13 /var/www/project_test/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Events/Dispatcher.php(199): Illuminate\Events\Dispatcher->Illuminate\Events\{closure}('Illuminate\\Queu...', Array)
#14 /var/www/project_test/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Events/Dispatcher.php(172): Illuminate\Events\Dispatcher->dispatch('Illuminate\\Queu...', Array, false)
#15 /var/www/project_test/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/FailingJob.php(36): Illuminate\Events\Dispatcher->fire(Object(Illuminate\Queue\Events\JobFailed))
#16 /var/www/project_test/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Worker.php(392): Illuminate\Queue\FailingJob::handle('database', Object(Illuminate\Queue\Jobs\DatabaseJob), Object(Swift_TransportException))
#17 /var/www/project_test/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Worker.php(378): Illuminate\Queue\Worker->failJob('database', Object(Illuminate\Queue\Jobs\DatabaseJob), Object(Swift_TransportException))
#18 /var/www/project_test/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Worker.php(321): Illuminate\Queue\Worker->markJobAsFailedIfWillExceedMaxAttempts('database', Object(Illuminate\Queue\Jobs\DatabaseJob), 3, Object(Swift_TransportException))
#19 /var/www/project_test/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Worker.php(295): Illuminate\Queue\Worker->handleJobException('database', Object(Illuminate\Queue\Jobs\DatabaseJob), Object(Illuminate\Queue\WorkerOptions), Object(Swift_TransportException))
#20 /var/www/project_test/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Worker.php(258): Illuminate\Queue\Worker->process('database', Object(Illuminate\Queue\Jobs\DatabaseJob), Object(Illuminate\Queue\WorkerOptions))
#21 /var/www/project_test/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Worker.php(110): Illuminate\Queue\Worker->runJob(Object(Illuminate\Queue\Jobs\DatabaseJob), 'database', Object(Illuminate\Queue\WorkerOptions))
#22 /var/www/project_test/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Console/WorkCommand.php(100): Illuminate\Queue\Worker->daemon('database', 'default,q-mail', Object(Illuminate\Queue\WorkerOptions))
#23 /var/www/project_test/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Console/WorkCommand.php(83): Illuminate\Queue\Console\WorkCommand->runWorker('database', 'default,q-mail')
#24 [internal function]: Illuminate\Queue\Console\WorkCommand->fire()
#25 /var/www/project_test/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(29): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#26 /var/www/project_test/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(87): Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::Illuminate\Container\{closure}()
#27 /var/www/project_test/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(31): Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::callBoundMethod(Object(Illuminate\Foundation\Application), Array, Object(Closure))
#28 /var/www/project_test/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(524): Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::call(Object(Illuminate\Foundation\Application), Array, Array, NULL)
#29 /var/www/project_test/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Command.php(182): Illuminate\Container\Container->call(Array)
#30 /var/www/project_test/vendor/symfony/console/Command/Command.php(265): Illuminate\Console\Command->execute(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Illuminate\Console\OutputStyle))
#31 /var/www/project_test/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Command.php(167): Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Illuminate\Console\OutputStyle))
#32 /var/www/project_test/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(826): Illuminate\Console\Command->run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#33 /var/www/project_test/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(189): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand(Object(Illuminate\Queue\Console\WorkCommand), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#34 /var/www/project_test/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(120): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#35 /var/www/project_test/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/Kernel.php(123): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#36 /var/www/project_test/artisan(35): Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#37 {main}
```

Thank by advance for your responses,

Rergards

Answer (score 1):

Loooks like [themsaid](https://github.com/themsaid) answered your issue request on [laravel bug tracker](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/18440). To save others a click, I'll quote that reply here if you don't mind:

> Don't use the Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable, it's meant to be
>   used with Eloquent models, now the Queue driver will try to serliaize
>   your service provider thinking it's the notifiable, this is something
>   you don't want.
>
> Instead you can create a MySlack class or something that uses
>   Notifiable and you send the notification from the service provider
>   like:

```php
Notification::Send(new MySlack(), new MyNotification());
```

Comment: Yes it's solved thank to themsaid.
Moreover I answered on github with a detailed solution :
https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/18440#issuecomment-290992251

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have implemented `ShouldQueue` and use `Queueable` trait:

```
class MyNotification extends Notification implements ShouldQueue{
    use Queueable;

    // ...
}
```